# Finding the jnlp file that started a Java application (Java Web Start)

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

### Background

I've made a Java application that is started by downloading a dynamically generated .jnlp file. What the application does is not really relevant, but its a screenrecorder. The user will download and start several (maybe hundreds) of these applications over time.

### Problem

When the program ends I would like to delete the jnlp file that started the application. The point of the program is that nothing should be installed and nothing left behind. That includes the jnlp filed that one download to start it.

### Question

Is there a way to find the jnlp file so i can delete it? (Preferably a File object)

Comment: Will the user know the program is being run?

Comment: Ofcourse :P Not making anything like that :)

Comment: Then why is this important?  Also there might be _two_ copies of the JNLP file, and files cached in the Java WebStart cache.

Comment: OCD? :P As I mentioned, the user can download a whole bunch of jnlp files and I wanted to reduce the cluttering in the users download window :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up system property var `jnlpx.origFilenameArg` and delete it from the java application.

This worked on Java 6 update 26.

Comment: I've been using this env variable to delete the .jnlp file that launched the JWS app and it's been working great on Linux and Windows using Java 6 and Java 7.

Then, I tried this on Mac OSX Lion using Java 6 update 29 (Apple provided Java), and there is no variable called "jnlpx.origFilenameArg".

Any idea how to accomplish the same on Mac OSX Lion?

Comment: Unless this is guaranteed in the specification, you are basically vendor dependent

Comment: This no longer works on java 7u40 and java 7u45. Is there a work around?

Comment: Good question.  The java webstart classes are not open sourced and this is not described in the documentation so you are vendor dependent.  You may want to peek with a decompiler in the jar.